# C Typedef Struct / Union auto-cast

Tags: c

Im having a small math library for 3d vector and Im trying to "unify" it.

Instead of having multiple typedef struct for vector3f, vector3i, color3, angles etc... Im trying to put everything inside the same struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
            float x;
            float r;
            float ax;

            int   x_int;
    };

    union
    {        
            float y;
            float g;
            float ay;

            int   y_int;
    };


    union
    {
            float z;
            float b;
            float az;

            int   z_int;                
    };

} vec3;
```

Everything works peachy as long as the type is float, however when it falls to int Im having some strange values (which is understandable). My question is: Is there a way to cast directly/automatically inside the structure definition or I have to create extra functions to typecast between float and int?

---

Due to the answers below, maybe I should modify my original question to the following:

What is the best way to "unify" (and by unify I mean have like 1 struct) to be able to handle at the same time the following:

vector3f (float x,y,z)
vector3i (int x,y,z)
RGB (float r,g,b)
RGB (unsigned char r,g,b)
euler angle (ax, ay, az)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, you want to write into the struct/union as an `int`, but read out of it as a `float`?

Comment: Why not just keep it as floats, and when you need the integer value just cast the float member to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct genericStruct
{
    void *valueOne;
    void *valueTwo;
}GS;

int main()
{
    GS *gs = malloc(sizeof(*gs));
    int valueInt = 10;
    float valueFloat = 3.141592653589;
    int *inputIntPtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    float *inputFloatPtr = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    void *voidPtr = NULL;
    *inputIntPtr = valueInt;
    *inputFloatPtr = valueFloat;
    voidPtr = inputIntPtr;
    gs->valueOne = voidPtr;
    int *outputIntPtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    outputIntPtr = gs->valueOne;
    printf("Input ptr  = %d\n", *inputIntPtr);
    printf("Output ptr = %d\n", *outputIntPtr);
    voidPtr = inputFloatPtr;
    gs->valueTwo = voidPtr;
    float *outputFloatPtr = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    outputFloatPtr = gs->valueTwo;
    printf("Input ptr   = %f\n", *inputFloatPtr);
    printf("output ptr  = %f\n", *outputFloatPtr);
    free(gs);
    free(inputIntPtr);
    free(inputFloatPtr);
    free(outputIntPtr);
    free(outputFloatPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

And this what I meant by using void types.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to put '360.0f' into float z of a union and have int z_int == 3, or vice versa,  **you can't**.  That is not the purpose of a union, and the binary representation of 3 (an integer) and 3.0 (a floating point value) are *dissimiliar*.

However, you could just remove the int and cast one of the floats to an int.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small piece of code that i wrote for you.It should do the job.I hope i was able to do what you asked for...

```
typedef struct{


        void *ptr1;

        void *ptr2;

        void *ptr3;

}VEC;






main(){

        VEC v ;

        VEC *ptr;

        int a = 5;

        double b = 6;

        float c = 7;

        v.ptr1 = NULL;

        v.ptr2 = NULL;

        v.ptr3 = NULL;


        ptr = &v;

        v.ptr1 = (int *)&a;

        ptr->ptr1 = (int *)&a;

         v.ptr2 = (double *)&b;

        ptr->ptr2 = (double *)&b;

        v.ptr3 = (float *)&c;

        ptr->ptr3 = (float *)&c;

        printf("%d\n",*(int *)v.ptr1);

        printf("%d\n",*(int *)(ptr->ptr1));

        printf("%lf\n",*(double *)v.ptr2);

        printf("%lf\n",*(double *)(ptr->ptr2));

        printf("%f\n",*(float *)v.ptr3);

        printf("%f\n",*(float *)(ptr->ptr3));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or change all variables to void pointer type and then cast them to float or integer. Is it OK?

Comment: You can't assign a value to type void.

Comment: You can't even declare a variable with type void.

Comment: If you want to have generic struct:
typedef struct Abc_
{
   void *data1;
...
   void *dataN;
}Abc;
based on Mastering Algorithms with C by Kyle Loudon.

Comment: And then: for example - *intValue to *voidValue for input, *voidValue to *intValue for output. So it possible to declare and assign.

Comment: @Anthales, this is void type and per definition one has to use pointer to void type.

Comment: Again: The term "void type" hasn't got anything to do with the "pointer to void" type, void types are used as a "return type" for functions; I'm only talking about the semantics here - I understood, that you really meant `void *`

Comment: @Anthales Absolutely, you are right, as in the books I should write void pointer data type. My mistake.